# FlowLayoutPanel AutoSize only in vertical?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm loading images dynamically inside a `FlowLayoutPanel`. I need for this panel to auto-size but only vertically.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about achieving it?

Comment: _It's possible?_ Did you tried it?

Comment: I only set the AutoSize property from flowLayoutPanel = true; but the panel increase horizontally

Comment: Set the FlowBreak property on the controls you add to True.  If you add them in code then use the panel's SetFlowBreak() method.

Comment: You might also be interrested in this question which deals with pictures scaling in a FlowLayoutPanel : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930182/scale-components-in-flowlayout-as-big-as-possible

Answer (score 15):

Simple, add a event of type control added:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count % 10 == 0)
        flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(e.Control as Control, true);
}
```

set `AutoSize = true`

set `flowdirection = LeftToRight`

Comment: This will add the controls in a vertical way, but the list is now larger than my panel, and my scrollbar is gone, how do I get it back again?

Comment: @Giancarlo there could are multiple reasons why your scrollbar is not showing. All this does is set the amount of controls per a row. I suggest doing some further research and tinkering and if you still struggling ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
FlowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = False;
FlowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
```

will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I did set the Size from panel dinamically. Example:

> ```
> int newHeight= listImages.Count/10 * 100;
>                flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(1143, newHeight);
> ```

It works for me. Thx all

Comment: `int newHeight= listImages.Count/10 * 100;` is the same as int `newHeight= listImages.Count * 10;`

Comment: I know but *int newHeight= listImages.Count/10 * 100*; its better for understand that 10 is the number of pictures per line and 100 the height from each one

Comment: Hint: it would even be more readable and maintainable like this: `int newHeight= listImages.Count / numberOfPicturesPerLine * pictureHeight`, with definitions like `const int numberOfPicturesPerLine = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

This might look like an ugly solution, but it works for me:

1. Store current width of a panel in variable;
2. Set AutoSize mode to true;
3. Perform the action that require panel resize;
4. Restore previous panel's width from the variable.

   ```
               int i = _panel1.Width;
               _panel1.AutoSize = true;
               _panel1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
               /*some action going on here*/
               _panel1.AutoSize = false;
               _panel1.Size = new Size(_panel1.Width, 80);
   ```